# javascript error in image filter

Tags: javascript

So I am making a basic application that adds image filters to images. Here is the code.

```
class ImageUtils {

static getCanvas(w, h) {
    var c = document.querySelector("canvas");
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;
    return c;
}

static getPixels(img) {
    var c = ImageUtils.getCanvas(img.width, img.height);
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    return ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);
}

static putPixels(imageData, w, h) {
    var c = ImageUtils.getCanvas(w, h);
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

...

function makeMoreRed(img, adjustment){

 var pixels = ImageUtils.getPixels(img);
 var length = pixels.data.length;
 var data = pixels.data;

 for(var r = 0; r < length; r += 4) {
  data[r] += adjustment;
 }
 ImageUtils.putPixels(pixels, img.width. img.height);
}

...

$(document).ready(function() {
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = "img/cat.jpg";
 makeMoreRed(img, 50);
});
```

When I launch it with the webpage, Chrome throws this error
[javascript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvum7.png)

This does not make any sense as there is nothing but a semicolon at the end of the function.

Is there any solution on how to resolve this because here you can see that there is no change in the top image (the one that is supposed to be filtered)
[two cat pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRi4m.png)

Comment: you are missing comma `,` between width and height `ImageUtils.putPixels(pixels, img.width , img.height)`;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow a1phabeta. I totally understand your frustration with the error, but calling it *stupid* will make people have negative attitude to your question. Also, if possible, always try to first test your code on jsFiddle and see if the error happens there. If it does, you can post the code and link to your test, and you will get answer much faster!

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you have `.` instead of `,`:

```
ImageUtils.putPixels(pixels, img.width. img.height);
```

Compare:

```
ImageUtils.putPixels(pixels, img.width, img.height);
```

Please do not use StackOverflow to check your syntax, we're here to help with real problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a typo, you wrote

```
ImageUtils.putPixels(pixels, img.width. img.height);
```

but there has to be a comma after width instead of a dot.